# ImportError: No module named xlrd

Tags: python-3.x, importerror

I am working with Python 3 and trying to read a excel worksheet using `xlrd`.
I ran `pip install xlrd` to install it but it still shows me the `ImportError`. 
I tried the following:

1. `pip3 install xlrd`
2. `pip install --upgrade xlrd`

But both  of them show requirements already satisfied and up to date respectively.

Comment: python3 uses pip3. can you check if you are using the correct pip and python?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I realized I was opening python 2.7 instead of 3.6 on the command line and that was causing the error.

Comment: You can add that as an answer @SuryaAvala so that someone who's stuck with this doesnt have to go through the comments and can see an accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python3 uses pip3. Please check if you are using the correct pip and python version.